# Why isn't my umdf2 driver showing up in windbg's 'lm' command after successful execution?

Tags: windbg, umdf

I rewritten the wdm driver into umdf2 driver, and it was executed successfully, but I did not see my umdf2 driver when I used the windbg command "lm" (List Loaded Modules).

The same command can be seen in wdm driver. May I ask this Is it because of the umdf2 driver?

Comment: Do you do kernel debugging or user mode debugging? Do you debug one process or multiple processes in one WinDbg session?